# Custom Post Type Archive Template

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to set up a custom archive template for a custom post type I created in functions.php. Here is the code in functions:

```
add_action('init', 'create_post_type');
function create_post_type() {
    $labels = array(
        'name' => __('Portfolio Posts'),
        'singular_name' => __('Portfolio Post')
    );
    $args = array(
        'labels' => $labels,
        'public' => true,
        'has_archive' => true,
        'rewrite' => false,
        'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'excerpt'),
        'taxonomies' => array('category'),
    ); 
    register_post_type('cc-portfolio', $args);
}
```

I've also created my archive-cc-portfolio.php file.

The problem is, when I access the site http://site.com/cc-portfolio/ I get the default index.php file used as the template.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong or where to start looking?

Thanks,

Phil

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your archive page template will only show when you view a piece of content.

If you add content with title "abcd" and assuming you have permalinks as "%postname%", the you 
would access that content as

http://site.com/cc-portfolio/abcd.

I also believe that you need to name your template single-cc-portfolio.php

Have a look at the following plugin

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/custom-content-type-manager/

Try and play with that, and you'll probably see where you're going wrong :)

Thanks

Blake